# How to delete values from an array in PHP?

Tags: php

I need to delete the first 29 values of an array. I searched and there doesn't seem to be any built in PHP function that allows for this. How can this be done then?

Comment: In addition to the answers given: To delete a single value, use `unset`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array_splice) to remove values from an array:

```
array_splice($arr, 0, 29)
```

The array is passed as a reference as `array_splice` modifies the array itself. It returns an array of the values that have been removed.

Here’s an example for how it works:

```
$arr = range(1, 30);
$removed = array_splice($arr, 0, 29);
var_dump($arr);     // array(1) { [0]=> int(30) }
var_dump($removed); // array(29) { [0]=> int(1) … [28]=> int(29) }
```

In opposite to that, [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) (without *p*) just *copies* a part of an array without modifying it:

```
$arr = range(1, 30);
$copied = array_slice($arr, 29);
var_dump($arr);    // array(30) { [0]=> int(1) … [29]=> int(30) }
var_dump($copied); // array(1) { [0]=> int(30) }
```

Here `array_slice($arr, 29)` copies everything from the offset 29 on up to the end while leaving the `$arr` as is.

But as you said you want to delete values, `array_splice` seems to be the better choice instead of copying a part and re-assigning the copied part back to the variable like this:

```
 $arr = array_slice($arr, 29);
```

Because although this has the same effect (first 29 values are no longer there), you do the copy operation twice: create a new array and copy everything except the first 29 values and then re-assign that value to `$arr` (requires copying the whole array again).

Comment: This leaves me with the first 29 values, I want instead to remove the first 29 and be left with the rest.

Comment: @Sammy: As already said, `array_splice` modifies the passed array and only returns the values that have been removed.

Comment: ahhhh I didn't know it actually modifies the original array. I was able to achieve what I wanted by doing the array splice and not really using the returned value but instead calling on the original which after the splice had the first 29 values removed.

Comment: @Sammy: You should read more carefully instead of just copying the code. ;)

Comment: I just saw your edits when I refreshed the page after 10 minutes, before they weren't there.

Answer (score 4):

```
array_splice($array, 0, 29);
```

[`array_splice`](http://php.net/array_splice) deletes the elements from the array and returns the deleted elements.

Alternatively, if you want to keep the original array, but want to create a new array with the first 29 elements removed, use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice):

```
$newArray = array_slice($array, 29);
```

Comment: This leaves me with the first 29 values, I want instead to remove the first 29 and be left with the rest.

Comment: @Sammy: Are you sure you used array_s***p***lice? And are you sure you didn't assign the value (like `$array = array_splice($array, 0, 29)`, that would be wrong. You should not assign the value!)